# JSHint thinks Jasmine functions are undefined

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner, jshint

I've got a Grunt setup which uses Karma+Jasmine and JSHint. Whenever I run JSHint on my spec file, I get a series of "undefined" errors, most of which are for Jasmine's built-in functions. For example:

```
Running "jshint:test" (jshint) task

   js/main.spec.js
      3 |describe("loadMatrix()", function() {
         ^ 'describe' is not defined.
      4 |    it("should not assign a value if no arg is passed.", function() {
             ^ 'it' is not defined.
```

(I also get some undefined errors for the variables and functions from the JS file that my spec is meant to test against, but I'm not sure why that is and it may be a separate issue.)

My Karma config file has `frameworks: [ "jasmine" ]` in it, I don't have any globals set for JSHint, and I don't have a `.jshintrc` file since I'm configuring it in Grunt. I did try adding Jasmine's functions as JSHint globals in my Gruntfile at one point, but setting them as either `true` or `false` didn't make a difference—the errors still persisted when JSHint ran.

What am I missing? I can't seem to do anything to get JSHint to skip definition checking for Jasmine's functions in my spec file.

Comment: What version of Karma do you use?

Comment: karma 0.12.23, with karma-jasmine 0.2.0.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

MINOR CORRECTION - there should be "" around predef in the .jshintrc file.

Fixed by adding this to the `jshint` options in my `Gruntfile.coffee`:

```
predef: [
    "jasmine"
    "describe"
    "xdescribe"
    "before"
    "beforeEach"
    "after"
    "afterEach"
    "it"
    "xit"
    "it"
    "inject"
    "expect"
    "spyOn"
]
```

`.jshintrc`:

```
"predef": [
    "jasmine",
    "describe",
    "xdescribe",
    "before",
    "beforeEach",
    "after",
    "afterEach",
    "it",
    "xit",
    "it",
    "inject",
    "expect",
    "spyOn",
]
```

Comment: [the answer from Leon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27136840/3116322) should be the accepted answer because it's much shorter to define just `"jasmine": true`

Answer (score 69):

You can just add `"jasmine": true` to your `.jshintrc` file.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this in Gruntfile.js adding `jasmine: true` to the options of the jshint task:

```
jshint:
{
    options:
    {
        ...
        node: true,
        jasmine: true,
        ...
    },
    ...
},
```

Like the OP, I'm not using a .jshintrc file either.

Comment: Just that I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the other answers are correct, but I have never seen such exception before, however I see it now. Then I noticed that my tests are not in IIFE.
So I moved them in IIFE like this and I no longer get such JSHINT warnings.

```
(function () {

  describe('foo', () => {
     it('bar', () => {
        expect(1+1).toEqual(2);
     });
  });

})();
```