# Webstorm Jasmine integration - JSHint does not recognize jasmine

Tags: jasmine, webstorm

I set up Jasmine integration in Webstorm 8.0.4 using File > Settings > JavaScript > Libraries. I added a `karma-jasmine` library with the lib/ folder of my karma-jasmine node module.

This works fine in a way that syntax highlighting works, I can jump to the declaration and the documentation is displayed correctly. So the connection seem to be fine. However, JSHint still complains for each keyword about it not being defined, e.g.

```
JSHint: 'describe' is not defined. (117)
```

See also the following screenshot. As you can see, the syntax highlighting is fine, but I still get an error.

[image: webstorm jasmine integration JSHint]

Comment: This is answered correctly here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27136840/1264548

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering what I have from yeoman's build of my .jshintrc, yes you need to add these names to that file.

Annoying yes, unless you used something to scaffold with like, well, yeoman!

Here is the .jshintrc that yeoman creates for us - plus the addition of lodash/underscore and jQuery.

```
{
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "esnext": true,
    "bitwise": true,
    "camelcase": true,
    "curly": true,
    "eqeqeq": true,
    "immed": true,
    "indent": 4,
    "latedef": true,
    "newcap": true,
    "noarg": true,
    "quotmark": "single",
    "undef": true,
    "unused": true,
    "strict": true,
    "trailing": true,
    "smarttabs": true,
    "multistr": true,
    "globals": {
        "after": false,
        "afterEach": false,
        "angular": false,
        "before": false,
        "beforeEach": false,
        "browser": false,
        "describe": false,
        "expect": false,
        "inject": false,
        "it": false,
        "jasmine": false,
        "spyOn": false,            
        "$": false,
        "_": false
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could copy/paste the config as text instead of the screenshot, that would be awesome. That way, I (and others) could simply copy/paste it.

Comment: @StenMuchow, i copied and pasted the whole thing, webstorm still gives me those annoying red, what else did i miss? thanks

Comment: I somehow had to restart Webstorm after adding the globals in order to remove those annoying JSHint errors.

Answer (score 3):

It's a JSHint 'feature'. JSHint works on per-file basis and knows nothing about global variables and functions defined in other files unless they are added to 'global' list. This can be done by either adding the corresponding comments `(/* global MY_LIB*/` - see http://www.jshint.com/docs/) in code, or by adding variables/functions you'd like to use globally to the 'Predefined' list in `Preferences -> Javascript -> Code Quality Tool -> JSHint -> Predefined (,separated)`. It's the last item in the list of JSHint options

Comment: I don't understand. Am I supposed to add every keyword to this list of global variables?

Comment: not keywords, but names of all global objects defined outside of your spec file

Comment: yeah, so `describe`, `it`, `expect` and so forth, right? That seems ridiculous to me...